# How do I list out items that contain a certain letter no matter if it's cyrillic or latinic?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select all the names that contain the letter T both in cyrillic and latinic alphabet. It also doesn't matter if they're upper or lower case but I can manage that part.

this is what I'm doing now:

```
select *
from employees
where lower(name) like '%т%' or lower(name) like '%t%'
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide more informations of what you've done already.

Comment: Do you have a table of equivalent letters?  Do you want what a 6 year old would call the same, or what a linguist would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of, is to use Postgres array handling. It won't make the query faster, but at least a bit easier to write (I think).

You can convert a string to an array consisting of each character using `string_to_array()` with a null value as the delimiter. Once you have all characters as an array you can use the overlaps operator `&&` with a list of characters:

```
select *
from employees
where string_to_array(lower(name), null) && array['т', 't']
```

In theory you can create an index on the expression `string_to_array(lower(name), null)` - but I would be surprised if that did make it faster.